# Qt QMediaPlayer works only from main

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5

I built a simple media player in QT,
This is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

   QMediaPlayer* player = new QMediaPlayer;
   QVideoWidget *vw = new QVideoWidget;

   player->setVideoOutput(vw);
   w.setCentralWidget(vw);

   QFile io("C:\\file.mp4");
   io.open(QFile::ReadOnly);

   player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:\\file.mp4"), &io);

   vw->show();
   player->play();

   return a.exec();
```

}

when I try to run the code from the `MAIN.CPP` file it works and everything is fine.

When I try to run it from the file `MAINWINDOW.CPP` is not working (even do the code is the same except for this lines -

```
player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
vw= new QVideoWidget(this);

this->setCentralWidget(vw);
```

and `player` and `vw` are now in `MAINWINDOW.h` )

why is it happening?

Comment: probably your `QFile` going out of scope - try with `QFile *io = new QFile("C:\\file.mp4", this);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs:

> If a stream is supplied; media data will be read from it instead of
>   resolving the media source. In this case the media source may still be
>   used to resolve additional information about the media such as mime
>   type. The stream must be open and readable.

In your case the source of the stream is the QFile, but this is a local variable that will be deleted when the constructor is finished running. the solution is to create it in the heap

```
QFile *io = new QFile("C:\\file.mp4", this);
if(io->open(QFile::ReadOnly))
    player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:\\file.mp4"), io);
```